# How the query used in Yii2

Tags: yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Can you help me. i want to like [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lzgxt.png) but on my source code it becomes empty [emty](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vu0vT.png). What is the query or source code in my project? thank You.

in Controller

```
public function actionView($id)
{
    $con = Yii::$app->db;
    $sql = $con->createCommand("SELECT * FROM track where collecting_id=$id ORDER BY collecting_id desc");
    $posts = $sql->query();
    return $this->render('view', [
        'model' => $this->findModel($id),
        'posts' => $posts,
    ]);
}
```

in View

```
<div class="timeline__items">
<?php
foreach($posts as $row)
{
?>
<div class="timeline__item">
   <div class="timeline__content">
   <h2><?php echo $row['status']; ?></h2>
   <p><?php echo $row['tanggal']; ?></p>
</div>
</div>
<?php
}
?>
</div>
```

if the $id on the query is replaced with 'PMUEI' the result is [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QLXpI.png)

Use ActiveDataProvider

```
public function actionView($id)
    {
        $model = $this->findModel($id);
        $hotel = Track::find()->where(['collecting_id' => $model->collecting_id]);
        $posts = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $hotel,
        ]);
        // $con = Yii::$app->db;
        // $sql = $con->createCommand(
        // "SELECT * FROM track where collecting_id=:collecting_id ORDER BY collecting_id desc",
        // [':collecting_id' => '$id']
        // );
        // $posts = $sql->queryAll();
        return $this->render(
        'view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
            'posts' => $posts,
        ]);
    }
```

the result is [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/teJMq.png) .

Comment: $posts = $sql->queryAll();

To check what you got as return do the print, print_r($posts);

Comment: is there a special reason not using the `ActiveRecord` here

Comment: result. Array ( ) 1 @tigrasti

Comment: but i use code. $sql = $con->createCommand("SELECT * FROM track where collecting_id='PMUEI' ORDER BY collecting_id desc"); it's work. but if use $id become empty. How?

Comment: sorry, I don't know how to use activerecord in my code @MuhammadOmerAslam

Comment: print $id then. The problem is in your query.. And do " . $id . " to be sure :)

Comment: result is 11 @tigrasti

Comment: 'PMUEI' is not the same as 11. Be sure what kind of value you expect..

Comment: my post is updated. the expected results are at the bottom of my post @tigrasti

Comment: You are not sending good $id in the function. Go to url adress and check what id you are sending ... view?id=[here need to be valid value]

Comment: in the url of the result is view&id=1 @tigrasti

Comment: Try view?id=PMUEI and check the results. After that, if you want to continue working with yii2 you must learn some php basics...

Comment: I have to learn a lot @tigrasti. the result is error SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'PMUEI' in 'where clause'
The SQL being executed was: SELECT * FROM track where collecting_id=PMUEI ORDER BY collecting_id desc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its always good to bind parameters when comparing columns with any such input that is provided by the user or can be edited by the user as in your case is the `$id` that you are passing as a parameter to the `actionView()`. And then you need to use `queryAll()` or `queryOne()` in case you want multiple or single rows returned.

So you should change your query to the following

```
public function actionView($id)
{
    $con = Yii::$app->db;
    $sql = $con->createCommand(
        "SELECT * FROM track where collecting_id=:collecting_id ORDER BY collecting_id desc",
        [':collecting_id' => $id]
    );
    $posts = $sql->queryAll();
    return $this->render(
        'view', [
            'model' => $this->findModel($id),
            'posts' => $posts,
        ]
    );
}
```

---

Apart from the above, you should use ActiveRecord. Active Record provides an object-oriented interface for accessing and manipulating data stored in databases. Read [Here](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-active-record) to make your life easier.

Comment: it's work use ActiveRecord. thank you $posts = Track::find()->where(['collecting_id' => $model->collecting_id])
    ->all();